# Does Maimonides Allow Prayer to Angels?

Tags: tefilla, rambam, avodah-zarah, malach-angel, bathroom

In his Mishna Commentary to Sanhedrin 10:1 Maimonides lists as his 5th principle the prohibition to pray to an angel even as an intermediary.
He counts this in his enumeration of his 13 principles in his Mishne Torah as well (Hil. Tshuva ch. 3).

How then are we to understand his codification in Laws of Tfilla (7:5) of a prayer addressed to angels

וְכָל זְמַן שֶׁיִּכָּנֵס לְבֵית הַכִּסֵּא אוֹמֵר קֹדֶם שֶׁיִּכָּנֵס הִתְכַּבְּדוּ מְכֻבָּדִים קְדוֹשִׁים מְשָׁרְתֵי עֶלְיוֹן עִזְרוּנִי עִזְרוּנִי שִׁמְרוּנִי שִׁמְרוּנִי הַמְתִּינוּ לִי עַד שֶׁאֶכָּנֵס וְאֵצֵא שֶׁזֶּה דַּרְכָּן שֶׁל בְּנֵי אָדָם.
(Other versions of the text include even more prayer).

This formulation is more difficult as he writes elsewhere that the angels that accompany man are his positive and negative inclinations.
“It is to the good and the evil inclinations that they refer in their well-known words,"  Every person is accompanied by two angels, one being on his right side, one on his left." In the Babylonian Gemara (Shabbath 119b), they say distinctly of the two angels that one is good and one bad.” (Moreh Nevuchim 3:22; Friedlander Trans.)

For a similar presentation of the angels that accompany a person, see [Hil. Mezuzah 6:13](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2306n.htm).

Is it permissible to pray to one's inclinations?

Comment: This "supplication" is very much not the concept of prayer as the Rambam discusses it. Asking a malach to wait outside for you (as one might do for a friend) is a far cry from asking a malach to answer his prayers as one does for Hashem. Still, your latter point is intriguing...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky 
 
עִזְרוּנִי שִׁמְרוּנִי is more than a request that they wait for you...BTW I saw someone else make the point about the Rambam.

Comment: Shimruni is related to the term "mishomrim laboker" which implies attentiveness, not guarding per se.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky afilu im timtza lomar hachi (I wouldve cited the verese v'aviv shamar es hadavar) the term עִזְרוּנִי is certainly a prayer. If I recall the Qafih edition includes ברכוני also.

Comment: There is a slicha that Davens to the Middot of Hashem. My shul's Rabbi Paskened to skip it in shul.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot Yeah that is directly related. Those who hold like Rambam tend to skip it.

Comment: @mevaqesh thanks for the bounty-points! It's nice to get rep even though I don't post so much anymore :-)

Comment: @Matt You are very welcome. I was worried that you frequent the site so infrequently, that you would fail to notice. I am glad that that did not occur.

Comment: @mevaqesh https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8F_PW9P6dqlSnpOUE9jUFlzWkU interesting article i found in my libary that reminded me of your question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is indeed at least unnamed but very early Rabbi who believed this prayer to be proof that there's no prohibition of praying to angels. See the responsum published by Simcha Emanuel in Hamayaan, Tishrei 5758. ([This article](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Machnisei_Rachamim_1.pdf) attributes the same responsum to R. Eliezer Rokeach, though this is not necessarily correct).

Also, before answering the question directly, I'll note that Maimonides/Rambam does not believe that Biblical or Talmudic angels are to always be understood as man's inclinations (see the Commentary to Sanhedrin 10:1, for example, where they are intermediaries for prophecy). Just because he offers that explanation of a passage in Shabbos 119b, he wouldn't necessarily believe the same about these "angels".

Actually, there's a huge body of literature regarding what exactly would be problematic, in Maimonides'/Rambam's view, regarding 'praying to' (or making requests of) angels. I can't find a link right now to all of the many (approx. 30) sources that I know of myself. However, there are less sources dealing directly with this particular prayer, and I'll be happy to discuss those answer.

1. One explanation is that Maimonides/Rambam probably did not have the version of the text that you cite above, but rather a version that lacked the phrase "עזרוני עזרוני" (as testified by the [Bodleian MS. Huntington 80](http://www.jewishhistory.com/HARAMBAM/), the copy autographed by its great author).  Thus, the only problematic two words (which seem like a 'prayer'), would be "שמרוני שמרוני", "protect me". However, R. Yehudah ben Yakar, in his commentary to the Siddur, explains that the phrase should be translated as "wait for me", just as the verse, "ואביו שמר את הדבר". (He recognizes that this renders the next phrase, המתינו לי as redundant, and his response to that issue is merely to not include it). This explanation is also suggested by R. Meir HaMeili of Narbonne (in the book Milchemes Mitzvah, printed in the back of his Sefer HaMeoros on Maseches Berachos)
2. Rabbeinu Manoach, a very early commentator on the Rambam, writes that this prayer is indeed directed not to angels, but to certain intellectual faculties. By saying this 'prayer' before entering the lavatory, a person is actually reinforcing (to himself) that he shouldn't be fully using his rational faculty while in there (I assume because one is not permitted to study Torah in the bathroom) but at the same time doesn't want to abandon it completely.
3. Another source that I know of which addresses this issue directly is R. Yaakov Emden in his commentary on the Tur, Mor U-Ketziah (O.C. 3). There, he explains that because he refers to the angels as משרתי עליון, it's clear that he doesn't believe that the angels have any independent agency, but he's speaking to them as emissaries of God. He believes that doing so avoids running afoul of Maimonides' 5th principle, which is merely that is isn't worth requesting anything of angels because they cannot act against God's will; here, a person is merely asking that they perform God's will happily. (See Abarbanel in Rosh Amanah ch. 12, and R. Moshe Feinstein, Iggros Moshe vol 8, O.C. 5:43:6). Personally, I'm not so convinced that Rambam/Maimonides would really be OK with this, especially if his source is the Talmud Yerushalmi 9:1)
4. R. Asher Weiss discussed this question in a shiur from September 2006 ([available here](http://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Shiurim.aspx?Path=Hebrew%7CHTnc%7CParashaShiur%7CR0007-1%7CPrevLessons%7CMoadeyShana%7CYamimNorayim%7CElul)) and said that careful reading of Maimonides in both his Commentary to Sanhedrin as well as in Hil. Teshuvah 3:7 shows that he only prohibits prayer to angels if done as an expression of their status as intermediaries between oneself and God or serves them. However, if one merely "prays" to them to ask them a favor, this is not considered serving the angels in any way and is thus permitted. (However, this still seems to be against the Ramban in his "Toras H' Temimah", R. Yehudah ben Yakar in his commentary to Tachanun, and R. Shimon ben Tzemach Duran in Magen Avos ch. 4)

Comment: [This article](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Machnisei_Rachamim_2.pdf) seems like it's pretty good

Comment: 1) Thank You very much. I am almost certain the Qafih edition includes the words ברכוני though. 2) I dont see how that helps so much. Rambam writes (IIRC) that הוא לבדו ראוי להתחנן or some such (an equal question on 4). 3) If they dont have free will (as I believe Rambam holds except for a difficult passage in IT) then what does encouraging them to be happy accomplish? BTW I think that your answer is without exaggeration a masterpiece!!

Comment: The viewer on the Oxford page wasnt working for me. Could you please transcribe the text?

Comment: @mevaqesh I too am not convinced that Rambam himself would agree to the latter three, but I am more confident of the first. I sadly do not have easy access to Qafih's edition, but I doubt he'd go against the Huntington 80. Unfortunately, it appears that the website is currently having problems and I don't have a text version, but I'm pretty sure that the text is התכבדו מכובדים קדושים
 משרתי עליון שמרוני שמרוני עד שאכנס ואצא

Comment: @mevaqesh but re:2, encouraging yourself cannot possibly be considered a prayer, and would this be allowed

Comment: My point was about the angels that accompany a person in particular.

Comment: @mevaqesh it might still be permissible to speak to them in a non-supplicatory manner, since the function is not meant for them to act upon this statement at all, but a means of self-encouragement. BTW, note R' Avraham ben haRambam on this week's parsha by המלאך הגואל אותי

Comment: Which point are you referring to regarding non supplicatory speech? Nice reference to Rabbenu Avraham. And note Wiesenberg's understanding, which carries significance.

Comment: @mevaqesh re:2. I have the Wiesenberg-Sassoon edition, but what do you mean "his understanding"?

Comment: I appreciated your citation of rabenu avraham in the parsha and noted that wiesenberg writes that it world be fully forbidden

Answer (score 3):

Never did the Rambam understand this declaration as a "prayer" nor at any time did he deem requests or favors be permissible to ask of *mal'akhim* ("angels").

In an article written for the monthly newsletter of *Makhon Mosheh* and *Halikhoth `Am Yisra'el* - *Or HeHalikhoth* - by Rabbi Dr. Hhananel Sari (*Shevat*, 5773), the position of the Rambam from his own writings is explanation as regards the nature of *mal'akhim* and specifically the purpose and identity those that are constantly referred to by *Hazal* as accompanying each person.

> ...the *mal'akhei ha-shareth* that the *gemara* describes such as that they accompany a person [home from the *beth kenesseth*] on *Shabbath*, they appear to be the same *mal'akhim* that are mentioned in other places in the words of *Hazal*. They testify to the deeds of a person if he acts in a way that is not appropriate (cf. *Ta`anith* 11a), and from them it seems that a person needs to separate with apologies before they enter to perform their needs (i.e. use the bathroom - cf. *Berakhoth* 60b). The *Shulhhan Arukh* writes that today we no longer have the custom to say this apology, called "*hithkhabdu mekhubadim*" (OH 3:1), since we are not so strong in our *yirath shamayyim* that *mal'akhim* accompany us (cf. *Mishnah Berurah*). In the *sefer* "*Kaf HaHhayyim*" an opinion is brought in opposition to this that there are *mequbalim* who recommend to say it also in our times, since these *mal'akhim* continue to accompany each person also today. This *mahhloqeth*, whether or not *mal'akhim* still accompany people in our generation and if it is feasible to turn to them, for they comment on their observation that it accomplishes not only a positive assistance but it is also involved in [promoting] a more meticulous inspection of our deeds, these are debated due to a conception of *mal'akhim* which is far removed from that of the Rambam. In the *Moreh Nevukhim* (2:6, 3:22) the Rambam, in dealing with the explanation of the nature of *mal'akhim*, mentions that the meaning of the "*mal'akh*" is not always consistent, however the basic meaning is always "*shaliahh*". Because of this, each *navi* is worthy of being called by this name and even forces of nature through which *HaQadhosh Barukh Hu* manages His world, all of them are worthy to be called "*mal'akhim*" and they are known as the *pamalya shel ma'alah* (i.e. the entourage of *HaQadhosh Barukh Hu*). After this introduction, the Rambam brings a passage from *Midrash Qoheleth* that tells how when a person sleeps "*nafsho omereth le-mal'akh umal'akh omer le-keruv* - his soul speaks to the 'angel' and the angel speaks to the 'cherub'." And from here he learns that in the language of *Hazal* the creative faculty of a person is called a "*mal'akh*" ('angel') and his intelligence is called "*keruv*" ('cherub'). The Rambam knew that the majority of people were not accustomed to designating these parts of the soul as being *mal'akhim* and would even resist to accept this fact, therefore continues and says, "How important this is for the one who knows, and how ugly it is to those who are fools." We find therefore who these *mal'akhim* are according to the Rambam that accompany a person to every place that he goes, and it is clear now that in his opinion each person is accompanied by these two *mal'akhim* also in our times. Now it only reamins to clarify who is the "evil *mal'akh*" and who is the "good *mal'akh*." The question is not so difficult, yet the Rambam also deals with this question, but in another chapter of the *Moreh* (2:12).

Making requests - either for intercession or favors - from objects or beings other than HaShem is a violation of the 5th principle of Jewish faith and is the basis of all idolatry. Even *nevi'im* who receive their prophecies through the agency of a *mal'akh* don't ever make requests of them. Instead, they pray directly to God and allow God to use whatever means He deems necessary.

This particular statement amounts to little more than reminding one to hold off thinking holy and religiously constructive thoughts while in the bathroom until he finishes and exits. There is no prayer here and the phrases of "help me" and "guard me" etc. are later additions made by those who took this statement as a prayer to angels for protection from demons that supposedly live in the bathroom.

Hope this helps. Kol tuv.

Comment: Whence do you see the fifth principle limited to spiritual beings?

Comment: The reasoning of the Shulchan Aruch is not that we don't have the angels but that we aren't such Yirai Shamayim to always be conscious of the company of angels.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I hear you and I guess I don't, but I had in mind "prayer" to "angels" specifically. But I agree with you that the 5th principle includes physical beings as well - such as "rebbes" and other such people, animals, the sun, moon, stars etc.

Comment: @Maimonist What about asking me a favor ("can you please delete this comment later?") or telling an animal to do a trick ("sit, Rover!") or a "rebbe" to pass the soda ("Can the Rebbe please pass the _Beer Mayim Chayim_?")? Doesn't that count as asking for a favor from a physical being?

Comment: Dude, it's midnight. What do you want that I should say? :) I don't mean to make light of your concerns just that I'm having trouble seeing straight.

Comment: :) I was hoping you had a source for your spiritual/physical distinction, which would answer the question raised by my examples nicely. The other possibility is to differentiate between different kinds of requests, which gets more complicated.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I'll look for one...when my eyes work again. :)

Comment: @DoubleAA The Maharal I referenced in my answer makes the distinction that when you ask a person to pray for you, you are asking him for a favor, a Chessed. By angels this does not apply, he says.

Answer (score 1):

The Maharal in Nesivas Olam (Nesiv Hoavoda 12) discusses the issue of Machnisei Rachamim. He is completely in line with the Rambam that it is absolutely Assur to pray to angels. However, he writes that it would be ok to say it as a command rather than a prayer.

In our case, this 'prayer' is actually *telling* them to wait rather than begging or praying to them. It seems that a function of this recital is to keep in mind that Hashem send us angels to protect us.